# fatal error Eigen/core: No such file or directory

Tags: eigen, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

i'm trying to use eigen with ros electric. I don't know if I'm missing some aspects or just misunderstand the whole thing.
I installed eigen via

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-eigen
```

As mentioned in the eigen Wiki for electric Installation I downloaded the FindEigen.cmake and moved it in the cmake directory of my package.

In the CMakeList.txt I appended

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Furthermore I edited the manifest.xml and included

```
<depend package="common_rosdeps" />
<rosdep name="eigen" />
```

But now I don't know how to include it within my cpp file. I've had look at the laser_geometry package, where the FindEigen.cmake comes from, but if I do it like this

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <Eigen/Core>
...
```

i get an error making my package:

```
fatal error Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
```

What do i have to include within my cpp file or am I doing something else quite wrong? Most information I've found does not cover my problem or is referring to Fuerte installs.

thanking you in anticipation

Ah, ok sorry. Just referred to the errors. Here the rosmake output:

```
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['testEigen']                                                         
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['testEigen']                                                                 
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/namco/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121107-163504                           
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['testEigen'] to:
['testEigen']                                                         
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages testEigen.  This may take a few seconds.                     
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages                                                                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild                                                                                                                   
 No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                                                                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang                                                                                                                     
 No Makefile in package roslang                                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common                                                                                                               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits                                                                                                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                                                                                                                           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                                                                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization                                                                                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp                                                                                                                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole                                                                                                               
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs                                                                                                                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                                                                                                                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps                                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs                                                                                                         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp                                                                                                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> testEigen [ make ]                                                                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] All 37 linesestEigen: 4.0 sec ]                                                                                                              [ 1 Active 14/15 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package testEigen
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
  
      CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
  
  
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build
  cd build && make -l2
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/testEigen.dir/src/testEigen.o
  /home/namco/ros/testEigen/src/testEigen.cpp:2:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/testEigen.dir/src/testEigen.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/testEigen.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package testEigen written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/namco/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121107-163504/testEigen/build_output.log                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< testEigen [FAIL] [ 4.07 seconds ]                                                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package testEigen. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                        
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                                
[ rosmake ] Built 15 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                             
[ rosmake ] /home/namco/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121107-163504
```

And here the make VERBOSE=1 output

```
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
Re-run cmake no build system arguments
[rosbuild] Building package testEigen
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE


-- Build files have been written to: /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build
cd build && make 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/namco/ros/testEigen -B/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build/CMakeFiles /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/rospack_genmsg_libexe.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/rospack_genmsg_libexe.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
cd /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/namco/ros/testEigen /home/namco/ros/testEigen /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build/CMakeFiles/rospack_genmsg_libexe.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/rospack_genmsg_libexe.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/rospack_genmsg_libexe.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `CMakeFiles/rospack_genmsg_libexe.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build/CMakeFiles 
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
make -f CMakeFiles/rosbuild_precompile.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/rosbuild_precompile.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
cd /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/namco/ros/testEigen /home/namco/ros/testEigen /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build/CMakeFiles/rosbuild_precompile.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/rosbuild_precompile.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/rosbuild_precompile.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `CMakeFiles/rosbuild_precompile.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build/CMakeFiles 
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
make -f CMakeFiles/testEigen.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/testEigen.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
cd /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/namco/ros/testEigen /home/namco/ros/testEigen /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build/CMakeFiles/testEigen.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/testEigen.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/testEigen.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/namco/ros/testEigen/build/CMakeFiles 1
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/testEigen.dir/src/testEigen.o
/usr/bin/c++    -O2 -g -I/home/namco/ros/testEigen/include -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/msg_gen/cpp/include -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/srv_gen/cpp/include -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization/include -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/xmlrpcpp/src -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/include -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/rostime/include -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/cpp_common/include -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/messages/rosgraph_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/messages/std_msgs/include -I/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/messages/std_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include -I/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/msg_gen/cpp/include -I/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/include -I/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rospack -I/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/rospack/include    -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME='"testEigen"' -W -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -fno-strict-aliasing -pthread -o CMakeFiles/testEigen.dir/src/testEigen.o -c /home/namco/ros/testEigen/src/testEigen.cpp
/home/namco/ros/testEigen/src/testEigen.cpp:2:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/testEigen.dir/src/testEigen.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/testEigen.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/namco/ros/testEigen/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry for answering own post, fixed it (but you comments also disappeared). Not familiar with ROS answers yet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47665/fatal-error-eigen/core:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [boFFeL](https://answers.ros.org/users/3540/boffel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-11-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-07**:
Did you get any other errors? What is the output of `VERBOSE=1 make`?

**Comment by [boFFeL](https://answers.ros.org/users/3540/boffel/) on 2012-11-07**:
No, when i do make VERBOSE=1 it's the same. Only this error and after that compilation is terminated.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-07**:
I'm sure, there is more output than just the error. Please provide the COMPLETE output.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-07**:
eigen is not added to the include. If it is installed, check the output of the variables that FindEigen produces.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-07**:
Your fix is not a real fix. You basically manually specified to look in /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core. The original code was correct. The problem lies in the compile setup, which should add /usr/include/eigen3 to the include.

**Comment by [boFFeL](https://answers.ros.org/users/3540/boffel/) on 2012-11-07**:
Okay, I see what you mean. FindEigen should produce EIGEN_FOUND, EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR and EIGEN_VERSION, correct? So they should be via echo $EIGEN_FOUND available after rosmake? Or after running CMakeList.txt? I use QtCreator in which i can run them. Nevertheless there are no Variables available.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-07**:
Yes, those should be produced. Either they are not produced or  not used for some reason.Those are not environment variables, but CMAKE variables. You can use cmake's message function to output them.

**Comment by [boFFeL](https://answers.ros.org/users/3540/boffel/) on 2012-11-07**:
If I message Variables at the end of CMakeList.txt I get TRUE for EIGEN_FOUND, /usr/include/eigen3 for EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR and 3.0.1 for EIGEN_VERSION

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-07**:
Is EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS also set? You are using include_directories(EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS).  This is listed in the tutorial and I have that running successfully, too.

**Comment by [boFFeL](https://answers.ros.org/users/3540/boffel/) on 2012-11-08**:
It's also set to /usr/include/eigen3. Hmm :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that you are missing the dependency on eigen in manifest.xml.

You actually do not need FindEigen.cmake. The simplest (however incompatible to fuerte) way in electric is to use the ROS package `eigen`. It is a very simple dummy package that only exports the correct compiler/linker flags for linking against eigen. If you want to use it, just add

```
<depend package="eigen" />
```

to your manifest file and get rid of FindEigen and all other eigen related things in your CMakeLists.txt.

If you want to make your code future proof, I suggest to use pkg-config in your CMakeLists to find eigen instead of the FindEigen thing. For instance:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(EIGEN REQUIRED eigen3)

include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${EIGEN_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [boFFeL](https://answers.ros.org/users/3540/boffel/) on 2012-11-08**:
I'm not on the right computer to test it right now, but then i don't understand the eigen ROS Wiki concerning ROS electric. Anyway, also thanks for your reply...

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-08**:
I just provided alternative solutions that do not require to manually put FindEigen.cmake anywhere. The solution on the wiki should work, too.

**Comment by [ShubhamVerma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22795/shubhamverma/) on 2015-06-15**:
For ros indigo, also add following to your package.xml

```
 <build_depend>laser_geometry</build_depend>
 <build_depend>eigen</build_depend>
 <run_depend>laser_geometry</run_depend>
 <run_depend>eigen</run_depend>
```

Include "laser_geometry" to find_package(..) in CMakeLists.txt